# setInterval JS function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function every x-seconds,

```
setInterval( alert("Hello"),2000);
```

But the alert function appear just for the first call,

Comment: `setInterval(alert.bind(this, "hello"), 2000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert("Hello");
} ,2000);
```

It's not working like you thought. The `alert` fires/runs directly without interval because you've directly called it. To be more clerer, in your code:

```
setInterval(alert("Hello"),2000);
```

You are calling the `alert("Hello")` but you should pass a function (or bind) which you want to run on an interval, which is:

```
setInterval(function(){
    // ...
}, 2000);
```

So the passed `anonymous function` will be called using the given interval (`bind` is another way but I've used a `function/closure` for simplicity to clarify you).